# Status Bar Color is not getting set in OnCreate()

Tags: android

In Oncreate()/OnResume(), I am trying to change the status bar color. But the color is set and resetting to default color immediately.

Below is my code in OnCreate(),

```
 window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.online_status_bar));
```

So here, green color will display but suddenly green color is changed to default color. Where am i going wrong?

Any immediate help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have to set before `setContentView`

Comment: This is actually a fragment. And i want this color change only in this fragment. So I cannot edit the styles.xml.

Comment: I tried to set before super.onCreate(..). Still not working